# Laravel require at least one image

Tags: php, image, validation, laravel, file-upload

I am trying to force users to upload at least one image and at most 5 images. But does Laravel have any rules for this?

I am allowing multible image upload by setting my input name as `"images[]"`

then getting them by

```
$input::all(); $input['images']
```

For now I'm using

```
'images'=>'image|max:5400'
```

I want to force users to only upload images, and images with a max size of 5.4mb.

And I want users to at least upload 1 image, but at most 5 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Laravel docs. use [array-rule](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-array) and [max rule](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-max) and also [size rule](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-size)

```
$rules = ['images' => 'array|max:5|size:5400'];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

Comment: But will that still work when I am using "image"-rule? Which checks for jpg,png,gif,bnp. Also I am using multible images so the validation should be inside a foreach

Comment: @user2722667 use mimes rule `mimes:jpeg,bmp,png`, get file one by one in foreach what the problem?